# Stream to VLC for iOS via URL Scheme with Subtitle

Tags: ios, swift, vlc

Any way to stream a video to the VLC app with a Subtitle URL

like this :

```
vlc-x-callback://x-callback-url/stream?url=URL&subtitle=SUBTITLE.srt
```

i searched for a parameter or something but i found nothing

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no designated subtitle argument as of yet as documented on our wiki: https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:IOS/#x-callback-url

Patch welcome!

Comment: Thanks for your answer ... any plans of adding subtitle parameter in the near future ?